# Calling a recursive function inside a class

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to call a recursive method in order to find path from root to node in a binary tree. There are few solns. for this problem on the internet, but I am trying to use slightly different approach by implementing a method inside a `Node` class.

Here is my logic for the soln.

```
    def apend(self, arr, target):
        """ arr is the list which has the path from root to target node, self is the root """
    
 
        if self is None:
            return False
        arr.append(self.data)
        if self.data==target:
            return True
        if self.left.apend(arr, target) or self.right.apend(arr, target):
            return True
        arr.pop()
        return False
```

I a perfectly okay with how this logic is working, means if the target is found in either right or left subtree return True.

My question is; what if `self` is a leaf node, i.e. `self.left is None`. same with `self. right`. In that case the recursive call is giving an error.
Can I get some help on how to rectify that situation? thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking if `self` is `None` you need to check if `self.left` or `self.right` is `None` before you make a recursive call.

```py
def apend(self, arr, target):
    """ arr is the list which has the path from root to target node, self is the root """


    arr.append(self.data)
    if self.data==target:
        return True
    if self.left is not None and self.left.apend(arr, target):
        return True
    if self.right is not None and self.right.apend(arr, target):
        return True
    arr.pop()
    return False
```

Comment: appreciate your feedback. As I'm understanding, we need to be sure that `self.right` or `self.left` is not `None` before making a recursive call on them.
As a follow-up, if the root of tree is None, how will that case be handled in this code. Can you kindly advise?

Comment: You need to handle that case before you call `apend` the first time: `if root is not None: root.apend(...)` Inside `apend`, `self` cannot be `None`.